# c# winform exe communicating with another c# winform - like COM

Tags: c#, com

Currently have - C# application communicates with c++ application via COM
Need - Same C# application communicating with a another C# application via COM or COM like interface. Both applications are C# executables.

Reflection won't work because the original C++ application (being converted to C#) needs to run as a standalone application. So does the original C# application.

I've tried reflection and actually use it in other places. But the standalone requirement cannot be changed. The original C++ application (converting to C#) controls hardware.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this can be done by creating a RCW (Runtime me callable wrapper). This will make .Net assembly to consume COM components. Please refer to the below link for details, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/runtime-callable-wrapper

Or try CCW (COM callable wrapper) if you want to consume .Net code to C++